# Alternatives to the CS:GO API?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I built a little CS:GO price check website and I already added the functionality to check the price of an item. The problem is: It only works if the CS:GO API (not the steam api) is online. To be honest it seems to me that the CS:GO API is only 4 hours up and the remaining time down.
(You can check with steamgaug.es)

My question is how other CS:GO websites like csgozone.net, csgo.exchange or csgobackpack.com get the current prices for the requested items?
Is there an alternative to the CS:GO API and why does Valve not care about the API?

What should i do if i need the float value or detailed information about a single item?

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue you could run into with any API.  The other side might go away at any time due to the API provider having problems or failure at any network point in between.  The answer is simple: **caching**.  Keep the answers you already received and you'll have an answer that may be stale, but is probably close enough to being correct that it is better than no data at all.  So pick a database and define your schema and start building your cache.